# App notifications don't dismiss when read on the site

Tags: feature-request, notifications, android-app

I absolutely love the notifications on my device by the way; they are awesome.

It would be great however if they automatically went away when I took action on the notification in the website.

Scenario

1. A user's question receives a comment
2. Notification appears on Android app
3. User views the comment via the site, notification dismissed on the site
4. Notification is still visible on the device

The principal: *If I've dismissed something anywhere it should be dismissed everywhere*